# getting fatal error if product images not uploaded

Tags: magento2.2, gallery

if there is no product image then getting this error on Magento 2.2

```
[Fri Oct 28 08:48:21.033726 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2669752] [client 47.15.21.175:0] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
[Fri Oct 28 08:48:21.033737 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2669752] [client 47.15.21.175:0] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/ch328094/web/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
[Fri Oct 28 08:48:21.033739 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2669752] [client 47.15.21.175:0] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /home/ch328094/web/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\View\\TemplateEngine\\Php->render(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\View\\Gallery\\Interceptor), '/home/ch328094/...', Array)
[Fri Oct 28 08:48:21.033758 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2669752] [client 47.15.21.175:0] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /home/ch328094/web/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\View\\TemplateEngine\\Php\\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array)
[Fri Oct 28 08:48:21.033760 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2669752] [client 47.15.21.175:0] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /home/ch328094/web/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\TemplateEngine\\Php\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento in /home/ch328094/web/example.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml on line 331
```

Comment: Seems like you're getting the  error from porto theme file at app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml. You will need to find the error there or post the file here so anyone can see what's going on with the code.